# Regex to replace a whole word in javascript inside an expression string

Tags: javascript, regex

I've found plenty of old threads that recommend using \b to delineate words in a text document, so you can replace whole words, but I have expressions that contain words that might not be delineated by whitespace, such as

```
MyFunction(Fred, True, False, MyVariableIsTrue, x==true?a:b)
```

In this case I want to end up with

```
MyFunction(Fred, 1, 0, MyVariableIsTrue, x==1?a:b)
```

So my current code

```
        return expr
            .replace(/true/gi, "1")
            .replace(/false/gi, "0")
```

isn't going to work because MyVariableIsTrue will become MyVariableIs1, whereas the \b method won't convert the x==true?a:b part

How can I do regex this so it will match "whole word" instances of true and false (case independently) ? thanks

Comment: I think [`.replace(/(^|\W)true(?!\w)/g, '$11')`](http://jsfiddle.net/r2rcr0aw/1/) should work in all contexts.

Comment: Both this and the accepted solution seem to work. I'm kind of in disbelief that the accepted solution did work, but the above seems safer, logically, maybe !! thank you

Comment: `/\btrue\b/gi` will work unless you add any non-word before or after `true`, like `/\b=true\b/g`. I did not post my solution as I got baffled by your *`\b` method won't convert...* and vks posted that very solution. It only proves the point you did some mistake during your testing, and the question was asked due to some typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   return expr
    .replace(/\btrue\b/gi, "1")
    .replace(/\bfalse\b/gi, "0")
```

Use `\b` which is `word boundary` for the same.